# I am having a syntax error and i have no clue on what to do

Tags: python, syntax

I was writing a code in a programming book for beginners.
This is what it looks like. (I HAVE TO EXTEND THIS POST BECAUSE THIS WEBSITE IS SO FINICKY ABOUT QUESTION POSTS.)

```
import random
print("You are in a dark room in a mysterious castle.")
print("In front of you are four doors. You must choose one.")
playerChoice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4...")
if playerChoice == "1":
        print("You found a room full of tresure. YOU'RE RICH!!!")
        print("GAME OVER, YOU WIN!")
elif playerChoice == "2":
        print("The door opens and an angry ogre hits you with his club.")
        print("GAME OVER, YOU DIED!")
elif playerChoice == "3":
        print("You encounter a sleeping dragon.")
        print("You can do either:")
        print("1) Try to steal some of the dragon's gold")
        print("2) Sneak around the dragon to the exit")
        dragonChoice = input("type 1 or 2...")
        if dragonChoice == "1":
            print("The dragon wakes up and eats you. You are delicious.")
            print("GAME OVER, YOU WERE EATEN ALIVE.")
        elif dragonChoice == "2":
            print("You sneak around the dragon and escape the castle, blinking in the sunshine.")
            print("GAME OVER, YOU ESCAPED THE CASTLE.")
        else:
                print("Sorry, you didn't enter 1 or 2.")

elif    playerChoice == "4":
            print("You enter a room with a sphinx.")
            print("It asks you to guess what number it is thinking of, betwwen 1 to 10.")
            number = int(input("What number do you choose?")
        if number == random.randint (1, 10)
                print("The sphinx hisses in dissapointment. You guessed correctly.")
                print("It must let you go free.")
                print("GAME OVER, YOU WIN.")             
        else:
             print("The sphinx tells you that your guess is incorrect.")
             print("You are now it's prisoner forever.")
             print("GAME OVER, YOU LOSE.")        
        else:
         print("sorry, you didn't enter 1, 2, 3, or 4...")
         print("YOU TURN BACK AND LEAVE (YOU COWARD)")
```

Comment: Pls fix the indentation of your code to what it actually looks like in your programm.

Comment: What error are you getting? Include the full input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two of your problems:

```
number = int(input("What number do you choose?")
if number == random.randint (1, 10)
```

The cast to `int` is missing a closing parenthesis and the `if` statement is missing a colon.

The last problem has to do with the double `else` statement at the end. Un-indent the last one, assuming that is what you wanted.

Fixed:

```
import random
print("You are in a dark room in a mysterious castle.")
print("In front of you are four doors. You must choose one.")
playerChoice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4...")
if playerChoice == "1":
    print("You found a room full of tresure. YOU'RE RICH!!!")
    print("GAME OVER, YOU WIN!")
elif playerChoice == "2":
    print("The door opens and an angry ogre hits you with his club.")
    print("GAME OVER, YOU DIED!")
elif playerChoice == "3":
    print("You encounter a sleeping dragon.")
    print("You can do either:")
    print("1) Try to steal some of the dragon's gold")
    print("2) Sneak around the dragon to the exit")
    dragonChoice = input("type 1 or 2...")
    if dragonChoice == "1":
        print("The dragon wakes up and eats you. You are delicious.")
        print("GAME OVER, YOU WERE EATEN ALIVE.")
    elif dragonChoice == "2":
        print(
            "You sneak around the dragon and escape the castle, blinking in the sunshine.")
        print("GAME OVER, YOU ESCAPED THE CASTLE.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you didn't enter 1 or 2.")

elif playerChoice == "4":
    print("You enter a room with a sphinx.")
    print("It asks you to guess what number it is thinking of, betwwen 1 to 10.")

    number = int(input("What number do you choose?"))

    if number == random.randint(1, 10):
        print("The sphinx hisses in dissapointment. You guessed correctly.")
        print("It must let you go free.")
        print("GAME OVER, YOU WIN.")
    else:
        print("The sphinx tells you that your guess is incorrect.")
        print("You are now it's prisoner forever.")
        print("GAME OVER, YOU LOSE.")
else:
    print("sorry, you didn't enter 1, 2, 3, or 4...")
    print("YOU TURN BACK AND LEAVE (YOU COWARD)")
```

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said; but I am now receiving indentation errors at this section:    if: number == random.randint (1, 10):
               print("The sphinx hisses in dissapointment. You guessed correctly.")
               print("It must let you go free.")
               print("GAME OVER, YOU WIN.")

Comment: @NigelAwrey I updated my answer to include the code in its entirety, even though only a part of it had syntax issues. I've tested and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a whitespace delimited language, which means you need to pay special attention to indentation. Your indentation is inconsistent which will inevitably lead to issues.

Other than that, you did not specify WHAT your error actually is. Add the syntax error information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

You just had some problems with spacing and forgot ":" in line 30

```
import random
print("You are in a dark room in a mysterious castle.")
print("In front of you are four doors. You must choose one.")
playerChoice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4...")
if playerChoice == "1":
        print("You found a room full of tresure. YOU'RE RICH!!!")
        print("GAME OVER, YOU WIN!")
elif playerChoice == "2":
        print("The door opens and an angry ogre hits you with his club.")
        print("GAME OVER, YOU DIED!")
elif playerChoice == "3":
        print("You encounter a sleeping dragon.")
        print("You can do either:")
        print("1) Try to steal some of the dragon's gold")
        print("2) Sneak around the dragon to the exit")
        dragonChoice = input("type 1 or 2...")
        if dragonChoice == "1":
            print("The dragon wakes up and eats you. You are delicious.")
            print("GAME OVER, YOU WERE EATEN ALIVE.")
        elif dragonChoice == "2":
            print("You sneak around the dragon and escape the castle, blinking in the sunshine.")
            print("GAME OVER, YOU ESCAPED THE CASTLE.")
        else:
            print("Sorry, you didn't enter 1 or 2.")

elif    playerChoice == "4":
            print("You enter a room with a sphinx.")
            print("It asks you to guess what number it is thinking of, betwwen 1 to 10.")
            number = int(input("What number do you choose?"))    
            if number == random.randint (1, 10):
                print("The sphinx hisses in dissapointment. You guessed correctly.")
                print("It must let you go free.")
                print("GAME OVER, YOU WIN.")             
            else:
                 print("The sphinx tells you that your guess is incorrect.")
                 print("You are now it's prisoner forever.")
                 print("GAME OVER, YOU LOSE.")        
else:
     print("sorry, you didn't enter 1, 2, 3, or 4...")
     print("YOU TURN BACK AND LEAVE (YOU COWARD)")
```